# TreatWarningsAsErrors vs /warnaserror

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, roslyn

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int unused = 3;
    }
}
```

If I add:

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

To the *.csproj file, then everytime I try to compile this program, the build will fail because the unused variable warning is promoted to an error. This is the same thing as setting the "Treat Warnings as errors" option under "Project > Properties" to "All" in the Visual Studio IDE.

Instead, if I compile like:

```
msbuild /warnaserror
```

The build will fail the first time, but binaries will still be produced, and therefore, every subsequent build will pass.

Is there a difference msbuild command line arguments and msbuild properties I am not understanding?

Also, I assume the msbuild command line arguments are not simply being passed to csc.exe, because if I do:

```
csc.exe -warnaserror Program.cs
```

No executable is produced and the build always fails.

Comment: There was an issue that msbuild (early msbuild 15 version(s)) sometimes doesn't fail when using the /warnaserror option (see here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1791). Not sure, though, whether newer/current versions of msbuild have this issue fixed or if this issue is still present...

Comment: GItHub indicates the issue was fixed in 15.2.0-preview-000083-02.

I am using msbuild 15.9.21.664.

I had heard about this issue previously, but I am also not using "/m" flag here either.

Comment: Try `msbuild /p:TreatWarningsAsErros=true …`

Comment: That's the same as providing the property in the *.csproj file, how is it different from "/warnaserror"?

Comment: For me with MSbuild version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 `msbuild -p:TreatWarningsAsErros=true` did prevent the generation of a target, whereas with `msbuild -warnaserror` a target was always created.

Comment: See also https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/3295

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/26199

Comment: `TreatWarningsAsErrors` 
spelling mistake.
instead of:
`TreatWarningsAsErros`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You’re right, the msbuild command line arguments are not simply being
> passed to csc.exe, especially for /warnaserror.

Though not finding a valid document which describes the relationship between `/warnaserror` in msbuild and in csc. There is something difference between warnaserror in msbuild options and that in csc options.

In msbuild: The description of it is: When a warning is treated as an error the target will continue to execute as if it was a warning but the overall build will fail. (We can see it by msbuild /help).

But in C# compile(csc): The [remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/warnaserror-compiler-option#remarks) is: Any messages that would ordinarily be reported as warnings are instead reported as errors, and the build process is halted (no output files are built).

When we build the project for first time, if we use msbuild /warnaserror. The error will be recognized and displayed by ‘CoreCompile’ Target and the screenshot is as below:
[image]
Yes, the build failed. But as mentioned above, the target will continue to execute when `using /warnaserror in msbuild`, which caused the output of .exe file in obj folder and then in bin folder.

But for `/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true`, if we use it to build for the first time. The build will fail like using /warnaserror in msbuild, but the `difference is the message should be /target:exe /warnaserror+ /utf8output instead of /target:exe /utf8output.`

This indicates that when `using /warnaserror in msbuild`, it doesn’t work as `/warnaserror in CSC`. Instead, the `/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true seems to work as calling the /warnaserror in CSC`.

**And I think that’s the difference between [/warnaserror in msbuild] and [/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true and csc -warnaserror]. Hope it helps solve your question.**

In addition: If you do want to treat warnings as errors and don’t want output of it. I suggest you use /p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true. And if for some special reason, you need a output when treating warnings as errors you can choose /warnaserror.

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Thanks, I have begun just using "/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true", msbuild "/warnaserror" does elevate MSBuild warnings to errors, whereas "/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true" only impacts csc errors.

Unfortunately, even though the MSBuild warnings are elevated, they still do not prevent the omission of the target. Which is baffling to me, what is the point of an error then?

Comment: @tmac Do you mean if you use /p:Treat...but still have the output even build fails or what? Delete the obj folder and try, if this persists, you can share more details here or open a new thread with detailed info.

Comment: No "/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true" properly elevates CSC warnings to errors, it does NOT promote MSBuild warnings to errors. These promoted CSC errors properly prevent the generation of a target.

The "/warnaserror" MSBuild flag, on the other hand, promotes both CSC and MSBuild warnings to errors, BUT these promoted errors do NOT prevent the generation of a target. This defeats the purpose of promoting a warning, IMO, because an error should prevent the generation of a target.

Comment: For this, i'm not sure why the purpose of promoting the warning with the target continues to execute. This may be more related to the design of the team. And since /p:treatWarning:... can't fully meet your needs about promoting the CSC errors.I think you can post your suggestion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild) or by reporting feedback in VS IDE.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/26199