# What is MSBUILD : Unknown switch error solution?

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I am trying to run a script via powershell.
But when I try to compile the "build.ps1" script via powershell, I get the following error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: /warnaserror

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
An error occurred when executing task 'Build-API'.
Error: One or more errors occurred.
MSBuild: Process returned an error (exit code 1).
```

(MSBuild version is : 14.0)

**Here is the github repository link of build.ps1 file :** [build.ps1](https://github.com/rticommunity/rticonnextdds-connector-cs/blob/master/build.ps1)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: can you post the content of build.ps1?

Comment: I added the github address of the file into the edit.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54783564/9898643).